# Check if any instances of class exist

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to check if there are any instances of a given class?

And if there is a way - is it also possible to retrieve these instances?

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: Some part of my code should change its behaviour depending on whether there exist instances of a class. It would be even better if it would be able to know exactly what kind of instances these are so the behaviour can be adjust thereafter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add each instance to an array in the constructor:

```js
class Abc {
  constructor(arg) {
    this.arg = arg;
    Abc.instances.push(this);
  }
}
Abc.instances = [];

new Abc('qwe');
new Abc('rty');
console.log(Abc.instances);
```

Comment: in other words, the only way this can be done is if you write your classes to store such information

Comment: Note that this is not really what OP requested. It's rather a workaround that have a pre-requisite.

Comment: Careful, this is a potential memory leak. No instance of `Abc` will be removed and garbage collected untill **you** remove it from `Abc.instances`

Comment: I will accept this answer since it seems that there isn't a different solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
class Instance{
  constructor(...args){
   //doSomething for init;
   Instance.HAS.add(this);
 }

}
Instance.HAS={
  instances:[],
add(instance){
this.instances.push(instance);
},
has(instance){
return this.instances.indexOf(instance)>-1;
},
all(){
 return this.instances;
}
};

let i1 = new Instance();
let i2 = new Instance();

console.info(Instance.HAS.all());
//VM1164:1 (2) [Instance, Instance]
console.info(Instance.HAS.has(i1));
//VM1245:1 true
```