# Is there any way to find out that how many instances has been created through a blueprint or class in js?

Tags: javascript, class, object, instance

Say I am creating total 5 instances from a class or blueprint. Can I have any property of that class which tells us that 5 object has been created through me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if any instances of class exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58319209/check-if-any-instances-of-class-exist)

Comment: If you only need the count, not the actual instances, use `Abc.count = 0` and `Abc.count++` instead of pushing to the array

Comment: Just put code in the constructor that counts how often it was called. It's not really a good practice though, why would you need this?

Comment: See actually i want that count from that blueprint. If say I am creating one property of that blueprint as count and whenever we are creating instance from that blueprint then it should increase by one. But I only can fetch it through its instance not by the blueprint itself.